# Входит ли строка в строку

Tags: php

Хочу реализовать, что бы при выборе страницы менялось активное меню.

Есть такое URL

```
/service/type/office_cleaning
```

Как проверить входит ли строка `/service`в строку`/service/type/office_cleaning` на php

Comment: Например - strpos. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "/service/type/office_cleaning";
$sch = "/service";

if(stristr($str, $sch)):// возвращает строку, регистронезависима
    echo "$sch in string \r\n";
endif;

if(strstr($str, $sch)):// возвращает строку, регистрозависима
    echo "$sch in string \r\n";
endif;

if(false !== stripos($str, $sch)):// возвращает позицию подстроки или false, регистронезависима
    print_r('вхождение строки: ' . stripos($str, $sch) . "\r\n");
endif;

if(false !== strpos($str, $sch)):// возвращает позицию подстроки, регистрозависима
    echo 'вхождение строки: ' . strpos($str, $sch) . "\r\n";
endif;

if(false !== preg_match('/\$str/', $sch)):// проверяет по regex
   echo 'соответствие строки: ' . preg_match('/\$str/', $sch) . "\r\n";
endif;
```

И там ещё кто знает, сколько способов.